# Display the selected value in dropdown without using javascript

Tags: magento, php

How to Display the selected value when the option is selected in dropdown menu in phtml without using javascript.here is what i have tried so far!.i am trying this one in magento

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/products/simpleproduct') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form-customer-product-new">
<table class="tablepostion">
<tr>
<td>
<select id="sizeoption">
<option value="1">Small</option>
<option value="2">Medium</option>
<option value="3">Large</option>
</select>
<?php 
$a = $_POST['sizeoption'];
echo $a;

?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to store this value in a variable

Answer (score 3):

```
You need to add name of your dropdown.

<select name="mysize" id="sizeoption">
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
</select>

<?php 
$a = $_REQUEST['mysize'];
echo $a;
?>

Thanks,
```

Comment: let me test it for you.
Thanks for inform dear.

Comment: still i am not getting answer i dont know what is the problem.i copied this entire code in my file,not showing anything.just the menu with values only shown.i am not getting value when i clicked the option in the menu

Comment: What you want to do with that selected value? You want to pass that value to any other page or anything else? please be clear.

Comment: i am trying to add all attributes of the products into magento from front end for that i added size attribute as dropdown.so i need the selected value specifially to store into magento we cant add all the sizes for one product so only

Comment: So have you created your own script or passing this to any controller?

Comment: own script i am not using any controller!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php $a = $_POST['sizeoption']; ?>
<table class="tablepostion">
  <tr>
      <td>
          <select id="sizeoption">
          <option <?php echo ($a ==1)?'selected="selected"' : '' ?>  value="1">Small</option>
          <option <?php echo ($a ==2)?'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="2">Medium</option>
          <option <?php echo ($a ==3)?'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="3">Large</option>
          </select>
      </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you are missing `"` quotes in `seleted=selected`

Comment: can u show me the full code man..still it is not coming for me

Comment: in your html change the place of <?php 
$a = $_POST['sizeoption'];
echo $a;

?> to top

Comment: i am not getting still only the dropdown is shown the selected value is not getting displayed i am new to php so only facing this small problem as difficult one